# Table in MailChimp doesn't overlay on the background

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqhe1.png)

I inserted a code block in the MailChimp template I'm creating. I need the table or the texts below to be on that image. I'm not an expert in programming, I asked for ChatGPT to code this and everything's okay when it's on the MailChimp preview. However, when I send test email, it becomes like that. The table appears below on the image.

Here's my code:

(sorry it's messy)

```
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      display: flex;
    }

    .container {
        position: relative;
    }

    .background-image {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left:2px;
    }

    .overlay-table {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 80%;
        margin-top:85px;
        margin-left:68px;
        table-layout:fixed;

    }

    .overlay-table table {
        width: 530px;
        margin:0px  auto;
        border-collapse: collapse;
                table-layout:fixed;
    }

    .overlay-table td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right:30px;
       width:10%;
        font-size: 12px;
        
    }
  
   .overlay-table tr {
        padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        text-align: center;
 
            
    }
  .white{
        color:#ffffff
    }
  
 
</style>


<!-- Email content -->
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://mcusercontent.com/fbb859e41b9c38d9b0605cda2/images/8db04116-c7dc-33e9-5479-53885ba2d8c6.png" alt="Image Description" class="background-image">

    <div>
      
  </div>
  
  <div class="overlay-table">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <!-- Row 1 -->
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><b>PM-7</b><br> PRIMO <br>7 Quater Mixer <br><br><b>AX-IB550</b><br> AXIS <br>Hand Held Mixer <br><br><b>IGF-35/40 NG</b><br> ΙΚΟΝ <br>Fryer 35/40 lbs <br><br><b>AX-VIB750</b><br> AXIS<br> Hand Held Mixer</td>
              <td><b>PS-12</b><br> PRIMO <br>12" Meat Slicer <br><br><b>PM-10</b><br> PRIMO<br> 10 QT Gear Mixer <br><br><b>SRSP-18-2</b><br>SIERRA<br>Gas Stock Pot 18" <br><br><b>AX-VIB750</b><br>AXIS Hand Held Mixer</td>
                <td>AXS10U AXIS Ultra 10" Slicer <br><br>AXS12U AXIS Ultra 12" Slicer<br><br></td>
                <td class="white">AX-VIB750 AXIS Hand Held Mixer</td>
              <td class="white"><b>AX-S14GIX</b><br>AXIS <br>Slicer 14"<br><br><b>LX-46RB</b><br> KOOL-IT SIGNATURE<br> Dbl Glass Door <br>Refrigerator <br>24 Cu Ft Blk<br><br><b>KBSR-2G </b><br>KOOL-IT SIGNATURE <br>Upright Bottom<br> Mount Refrigerator <br>With Glass Door <br><br><b>KGL-KRYSTAL</b><br>HYDRA-KOOL<br> Spot Merchandiser Blk</td>
            </tr>
           
            
        </tbody></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML and especially CSS inside email messages are notoriously limited because it basically only allows to use what existed 15 or 20 years ago, so that all emails stay compatible with all email viewing programs.

Comment: @PeterB thank you so much!! can I ask ChatGPT to create an older version of my code? what do you suggest?

Comment: You'll have to try that for yourself. Here's hoping that it has knowledge of this complex set of rules (which is several years old by now, so certainly not complete): https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/style-element/style-in-body/

Comment: can you debug my code please?

Comment: Use the link @PeterB has given you to check on each of the relevant CSS properties you are using. The most obvious problem would seem to be position: absolute which looks like it isn’t supported on quite a lot of email clients.

Comment: Also might be worth noting that background-image might help rather than using a separate img element. However, don’t rely on images being shown. email clients can have images switched off by default.

Answer (score 0):

Iam having the same problem, after some research I found out that email clients don't support any modern CSS technology. I found an old thread recommending using an email template client like [MJM](https://mjml.io/), still trying to figure it out,
"you can ask GPT to build you a template following **MJM** guidelines since it's before 2021"
also here is the link to the original [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736008/trouble-having-css-order-flex-box-work-in-an-email).

Comment: "email clients don't support any modern CSS technology" is quite a sweeping statement - email clients differ - and some don't support quite old CSS which is the problem here (position: absolute).

Comment: correct, after writing the comment and trying to convert one of my templates to a responsive email template using **MJM**, found a lot of info about email clients what they support, and what they don't.
Thanks, @AHaworth bringing this to my attention, I will add an edit to my answer to clarify my point.